# how to make a string an integer in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, int, helper

```
    Distance = input("How far are you from the spacecraft in meters? (full            positive numbers) \n")
number = Distance.isdigit()
while number == False:
    print ("Please enter a number or full number")
    Distance = input("How far are you from the spacecraft in meters? (full positive numbers) \n")
    number = Distance.isdigit()
while Distance < 600:
    print ("Please move back further from the space craft! \n")
    Distance = input("How far are you from the spacecraft in meters? (full positive numbers) \n")
```

So I am trying to compare a string to a integer but I'm not sure how to fix that with out breaking this part

number = Distance.isdigit()
while number == False:

Comment: You can cast: `Distance = int(input("blabla"))`

Comment: Try to cast using int(input("somestringinput")) and put it in **try-except** block to handle it properly when the input string is NAN.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this.

```
def is_digit(Distance):
    try:
        if int(Distance) & int(Distance) >0:
            return True
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
```